# saving pdf in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to save pdf in postgres database? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the datatype [bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html) to store the pdf. Another option could be a [large object](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/largeobjects.html), but that's not the easiest thing to use.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use BLOB type, postgresql bytea type

The quest is does it make sense?

Comment: Good question, but "yes" and "no" are both correct answers... It all depends! :)

Comment: why don't you use the file system and keep the path in postgresql?

Comment: Maybe because of data integrity, cascading deletes or simple backups? Using the file system has it's pro's and it's conn's, just like using the database for storage has it's pro's and conn's.